# Pass parameters to IFrame on dashboard CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dashboard, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to show a aspx page in an iframe on a custom dashboard. But this page needs some extra parameters. How can i adjust the url from this iframe so i can pass the values from crm 2011? I can't find where a trigger or something like that where i can call some javascript code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of information are you looking to pass?

If the record object-type code and unique identifier isn't enough, then you could do one of the following:

- use a web resource instead and have an iFrame inside the web resource.
- connect via the organization services from the custom aspx page and query what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option. I didn't knew it would be so easy ^^